# Error when creating a product Drupal commerce kickstart 2

Tags: commerce

I am using a Drupal commerce kickstart 2, whenever I create a product it gives me an error as it shows in the image,

![enter image description here][1]

any Ideas why?

Answer (score 4):

That's just a notice, I know it's unsightly but it doesn't necessarily indicate there's anything horribly wrong with your site.

If you can confirm this happens on a blank install of Drupal Commerce (which I'm pretty sure it won't), you should report it as a bug to the [Kickstart issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/commerce_kickstart?categories=bug).

Otherwise, looking at the backtrace, you're dealing with a bug/incompatibility between something in Commerce Kickstart and Pathauto/Page Manager,

Since pathauto is enabled by default in Kickstart, and Page Manager isn't, I'd strongly suggest the problem is incompatibility between Kickstart and Page Manager in some way. Try turning off Page Manager and see if you get the same problem.

If not, you've found the culprit, and should report it to the [CTools issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/ctools?categories=bug)

Comment: Hey Clive, 
Thanks for the response. I disabled the page manager and tried adding a product thankfully i didn't get the problem, but what should I do to use the page_manger again? am I to re-install it?

Comment: I mean to update module with latest?

Comment: That's a question for the CTools issue queue really, if there's an incompatibility between Page Manager and Kickstart it needs to be fixed by the maintainers of one of those modules. There's no guarantee that it's even been reported yet so the lastest dev version won't necessarily have a fix. I'd have a search through the CTools issue queue for that error message. If it hasn't been reported, get it added and hopefully it'll get patched up